# Using Salt To Encrypt Password PHP

Tags: php, security, salt

Here is my code,

```
    <?php 


    function($string){
    $salt = "@x5v";
    $hash = sha1(md5($salt.$string)).md5($string).sha1(md5($string));
    return $hash;
    }   
    ?>
    <?php

    print "<center>";
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    echo 'Variable is set and I can use it!';
   }
   $Username = $_POST["username"]; 
   $Password = md5($_POST["password.$hash"]);
   $Email  = $_POST["email"];


?>
```

I think it's this line causing the problem:

```
$Password = md5($_POST["password.$hash"]);
```

What would be the correct syntax to pass the users password into the database, encrypted with the string I defined above?

Comment: I hope salt is not a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it's this line causing the problem:
>
> $Password = md5($_POST["password.$hash"]);

What you are doing here is incorrect.  It should be:

```
$Password = md5($_POST["password"] . $hash);
```

What you were doing is actually indexing in to $_POST with a key that would have ended up something like 'password.fdg858fug83u5g5'.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this library instead of rolling your own solution:

http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Here's an article that explains how to use it:

http://sunnyis.me/blog/secure-passwords/

You should read this StackOverflow answer too:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/943102